# How to populate a SQL Server table continuosly with the data of another table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, random, fetch, sleep

I am struggling to convert an Oracle procedure to SQL Server (unfortunately without SQL Server knowledge). Basically the case is like this: assume that I have a table `HISTORIC_TABLE` with constant rows of data, and I have another table `REAL_TIME_TABLE` (totally empty at the beginning).

I am trying to generate transactions in `REAL_TIME_TABLE` by fetching rows in `HISTORIC_TABLE` randomly and slowly. Here the oracle equivalence of the scenario. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure test.p_replicate_data() 
is
cursor c1 is 
SELECT *  FROM TEST.HISTORIC_TABLE ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM;

r1 c1%rowtype;

cmd_sql varchar2(10000);
cmd_values varchar2(10000);

begin 

for r1 in c1 loop

cmd_sql := '';
cmd_values := '';

--start the command sql
cmd_sql := 'INSERT INTO TEST.REAL_TIME_TABLE (' ;

cmd_sql := cmd_sql || 'COL1, ';
cmd_sql := cmd_sql || 'COL2, ';
cmd_sql := cmd_sql || 'COL3, ';
cmd_sql := cmd_sql || 'COL4';


cmd_sql := cmd_sql || ') values (' ;

--prepare the values string
cmd_values := cmd_values || '''' || r1.COL1 || ''',';
cmd_values := cmd_values || '''' || r1.COL2 || ''',';
cmd_values := cmd_values || '''' || r1.COL3 || ''',';
cmd_values := cmd_values || '''' || r1.COL4 || '''';

cmd_sql := cmd_sql || cmd_values;

cmd_sql := cmd_sql || ')';

execute immediate (cmd_sql);
commit;

dbms_lock.sleep(0.05);

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean real time? Insert a record to REAL_TIME_TABLE  when new record comes out from HISTORIC_TABLE? or you need to transfer the existing record from HISTORIC_TABLE  to REAL_TIME_TABLE ?

Comment: Actually I need to transfer existing records. But the main thing is setting a cursor selects records in random order. So the procedure will never stop till I kill the process.